# PHPUnit --coverage-html not working

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, php-7

I am using PHP 7.0 and executing tests cases with PHPunit. those are working fine.
but when trying to run PHPUnit with --coverage-html option using PHPUnit 6.3.0 or 5.7.23, but it just displays available options rather than generating code coverage report.

I am not using any phpunit.xml file, is that mandatory and if yes then how to put my directory. I have two folders in my project - one for lib (core php class files) and another one for tests which has unit test cases.

Comment: `--coverage-html` requires an argument -- the directory to store the coverage report in.

Comment: I tried using directory name as argument 
phpunit --coverage-html tests

Comment: Post your command line.

Comment: @AlexHowansky  phpunit --coverage-html tests

Comment: `phpunit --coverage-html coverage_dir tests_dir`

Comment: Its showing 
Error: Incorrect whitelist config, no code coverage will be generated.

Comment: It's all in [the docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.whitelisting-files).

Comment: tried setting whitelist but it does not do anything, shows phpunit commands options only

Comment: `--whitelist` also requires an argument...

Comment: Try using an xml config file, perhaps based on the sample provided here: http://jenkins-php.org/download/phpunit.xml.dist `$ phpunit -c phpunit.xml` That will be eaiser than getting all of the options correct on the command line.

Comment: I tried with phpunit.xml, it shows me test coverage rather than source coverage.

Comment: can someone tell me exact working example for phpunit which will generate --coverage-html with project having lib (source files folder) and tests (unit test cases) folder, there is no bootstrap file only these two folders are there

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your code is inside standard directories (e.g. `src` for code and `tests` for tests), use the following phpuni.xml.dist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/7.0/phpunit.xsd"
    backupGlobals="false"
    colors="true"
    bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

then you can run `phpunit` to get tests without coverage and `phpunit coverage-html build` to get tests with coverage (feel free to replace `build` with any directory name you like)